# Mongodb is not connecting with external ip address

Tags: mongodb, networking, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to host the mean stack application in windows server R12 , Application is accessible when i use Private IP address of the server but it is not accessible when I user the external Ip address or the domain name of the server.I tried with bindIp with addition of One more Ip address. It is not working.

It is showing an error as below

> MongoDB shell version v4.0.1 connecting to:
> mongodb://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:27017/ 2018-08-09T16:53:22.656+0530 E QUERY
> [js] Error: couldn't connect to server xxx.xxx.xx.xx:27017, connection
> attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to
> xxx.xxx.xx.xx:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made
> because the target machine actively refused it. :
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13 @(connect):1:6 exception:
> connect failed

Answer (score 0):

mongod --repair worked for me ,

```
sudo mongod --repair
sudo mongod
```

Then open a different tab/terminal:

```
mongo
```

you can check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535985/couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017-connection-attempt-failed-mongodb/52536473#52536473)