# Couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 connection attempt failed MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am working on Ubuntu OS 16.04. I am starting mongodb using commands::
`sudo service mongod start` and then
`mongo`

It generated this error for me::

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-09-27T16:50:41.345+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Now I am not able to start mongodb. How to resolve this error and what are the causes of these error.
I tried all of solution for this problem but didn't find any solution.

Comment: It seems that your server did not start here. Did you try to see your mongod status using `sudo service mongod status` ?

Comment: yes I checked it's status and found there is some error in process::
`Process: 14618 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

mongod --repair worked for me ,

```
sudo mongod --repair
sudo mongod
```

Then open a different tab/terminal:

```
mongo
```

After this your local setup will work properly

Comment: is there a way to run `sudo mongod` and close the terminal?

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me **(MAC)**:

**Step 1** : Check the status if MongoDB is running or not

```
brew services list | grep mongo
```

**Step 2** : if you get something like :

```
Name           Status  User    Plist
mongodb        stopped
```

**Step 3:** : start the service:

```
brew services start mongodb
```

else :

if you get like this after step 2:

```
Name           Status  User    Plist
mongodb        started u1 /Users/u1/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

then it is already running 
then you can restart your service by

```
brew services restart mongodb
```

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, none of the above solutions worked for me. Looking at the mongodb logs, it seems the .sock socket file could not be unlinked, which is restricting the service from restarting. Doing the unlink manually and restarting is actually worked for me.

Checking last 100 lines of mongodb logs:

```
sudo tail -100 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log


{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T22:11:44.059-04:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T22:11:44.059-04:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T22:11:44.059-04:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Unlinking manually

```
sudo unlink /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Followed by start command

```
 sudo systemctl start mongod
```

A successful status returned :)

```
$ sudo systemctl status mongod
 mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-04-07 22:47:23 EDT; 6s ago
   Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 96418 (mongod)
 Memory: 177.0M
 CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
         └─96418 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Answer (score 7):

This error occurs when your `mongodb server` is not running on `27017` port.
Try the below command to start the mongodb server.

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

And after running this command run the `mongo` command.

Comment: I didn't created any systemd service for mongo. MongoDB is installed on my local system and I am trying to start this, but it is giving me this error again and again

Comment: Have you tried `mongod --repair` and then start mongodb server?

Comment: I got it, but still there is a question why it's not running with the previous commands

Comment: Most probably this was because of an unclean shutdown of mongod instance which leaves data in an inconsistent state. Explore [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/) for more.

Comment: With mongod --shutdown. You can its detail [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/).

Answer (score 6):

Windows

- Open task manager.
- click on the services tab.
- Search for MongoDB service.
- After selecting click on the 'view services' tab.
- Search for MongoDB server.
- After Selecting click on the Run button on the top left side menu.

And you are good to go.

Answer (score 5):

On MacOS , I executed the 4th step of this
`https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x-tarball/`

tutorial with  `sudo`

`sudo mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --logpath /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log --fork`

and It worked!

Comment: Thanks, this worked

Answer (score 2):

For windows,

1)Right click on the task bar and select Task Manager.

2)Select server at the given menu

3)Search mongoDB and select that and right click (click open services).

4)Search mongoDB Server, select that and click "start" at the left side window

Now it's ready to go

Comment: Thanks alot Dakshan!

Answer (score 0):

**MAC:** For my case I forgot to turn on mongo server locally, so I fixed the issue by firstly open a new tab on terminal then turn on mongodb server like so: -

```
mongod
```

After that just try to open mongo shell again like so: -

```
mongo
```

Finally it worked!

Answer (score 0):

i too got the same problem.here is the way how i resoleved.go to taskmanager.select>services and find mongodbserver in the list make sure the mongodb is running by selecting it.

[image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPcer.png)